# How do I archive or move recovery points to a new AppAssure core?

Tags: backup

I have an AppAssure core that had a few protected machines that were removed, but the recovery points were kept.

How do I get those formerly protected machines' recovery points moved to a different AppAssure core?  Or, how do I archive them to reclaim the space they're eating up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can archive a "removed" system, even if it's no longer protected.  After that, it's just a matter of presenting the media to the new Core and importing the archive.

To create an archive:

- Open the AppAssure Core Web Portal
- Go to Tools > Archive > Create
- Follow the Wizard

To import an archive:

- Open the AppAssure Core Web Portal
- Go to Tools > Archive > Import
- Follow the Wizard